# How to provide handle an event just one instance in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I handle events from Redis with 3 machine. But I don't want that if any events handle by x machine, other machines won't handle it.

I work on nodejs. I use subscribe method for handling.

```
Redis.psubscribe('__keyevent@0__:incrby...
```

I see [How to make sure my event is handled by only one instance of my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569688/how-to-make-sure-my-event-is-handled-by-only-one-instance-of-my-app) and [Competing Consumer on Redis Pub/Sub supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196306/competing-consumer-on-redis-pub-sub-supported), but they are really old. There may be better way.

Answer (score 2):

Redis pubsub isn't designed for such a use case. What you want can be achieved by using [Redis Streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro). It's released as part of Redis 5.0 a few days back. 
You can have 3 consumers (1 consumer per instance/machine) as part of the same consumer group which reads from a Redis stream. Redis will make sure the 3 consumers get distinct messages from the same stream.